# Change SendGrid unsubscribe page language?

Tags: sendgrid

As my company operates in Canada, it is required to have both French and English. Wondering how could you change the language of the build-in unsubscription preference management page?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. I'm in the same boat and finally ran across this during research:

> Because our native landing page is only in English, the only way for
> anyone with non-English speaking recipients to provide an opt-out
> landing page in a different language would be to use a custom
> unsubscribe link.

from https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260806604209-Unsubscribe-Methods